# React/Meteor - this.state from props gets undefined

Tags: reactjs, meteor, state, react-props, react-state

I need to pass props to my initial state for an edit form (as I want then the value of the form to be equal to the state) but I can't seem to have it working. The component doesn't give the props to the initialState as it firsts load with an empty props, I think due to the createContainer. I tried lot of things (componentDidMount, WillMount, WillReceiveProps...) but didn't succeed to have it work. The code is below, any idea to help ?

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import moment from 'moment';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

import { Blogposts } from './../api/blogposts';

export class BlogpostEditItem extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        title: this.props.blogpost.title,
        body: this.props.blogpost.body
    }
}

handleBodyChange(e) {
    const body = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ body });
}

handleTitleChange(e) {
    const title = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ title   });
}

onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.call('blogposts.update', this.props.blogpost._id, this.state.title, this.state.body,);
}

renderEditForm() {
    return(
        <div>
            <input onChange={this.handleTitleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.title} placeholder="Title" type="text"/>
            <textarea onChange={this.handleBodyChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.body} placeholder="Body"></textarea>
            <button onClick={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>Submit Blogpost</button>
        </div>
    )
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            { this.props.blogpost ? this.renderEditForm() : 'Pas de post' }
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default createContainer(({params}) => {
    Meteor.subscribe('blogposts');

    return {
        blogpost: Blogposts.findOne(params.id),
        call: Meteor.call
    }   
}, BlogpostEditItem)
```

I also tried to pass the props as defaultValue and keep the state as value but it doesn't allow to have both on a form. Any idea how I could solve my issue ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Inside** the constructor You get  as `props` not `this.props`
outside of the constructor, you should continue with `this.props`

```html
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        title: props.blogpost.title,
        body: props.blogpost.body
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel very much ashamed now :D Thanks a lot mate !

Comment: @Ivo: It would be great if you can mark it as answer :)

Comment: you saved my day